# Recycler view in android with async task

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to update the array list data in the background

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
      //intialization

    }




    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

     //doing major task

      //task here includes calling db and retrieving results and adding 
      //to list


     }

     @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

I am getting more views than adapter item count

my recycler adapter is like this in `onbindviewholder`

```
   List<Data> locallist;
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final innerclass holder, int position) 
   {

     Data data = locallist.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(data.number);
    holder.text.setText(data.text);
    }
```

Comment: how are you setting your data in the adapter?   before calling notifyDataSetChanged you need to update your adapter locallist . you need to provide more details about how you have setup your adapter class.

Comment: everything works fine if i don't use async task

Answer (score 0):

As first you define AsyncTask.

```
public class DataAsync extends AsyncTask<DataFragment, DataFragment, DataFragment> {

    private DataFragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected DataFragment doInBackground(DataFragment... fragments) {
        fragment = fragments[0];

        List<Data> data;

        // Doing major task...

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Data> data) {
        super.onPostExecute(fragment);

        fragment.setAdapter(data);
    }
}
```

Then you need to define setAdapter fragment's method.

```
public void setAdapter(List<Data> data) {
    adapter.setData(data);

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Next you define adapter's setData() method. It should do whatever you want on your array list.

You need also to define adapter in the fragment, just instiantiate it.

```
DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter();
```

Then execute task in your activity (you need the fragment instance as I said before).

```
new DataAsync().execute(fragment);
```

Comment: onpostexecute runs on ui thread and why can't i define there adaper.setdata and adpater.notifydatasetchanged, instead of DataFragment i used String and everything is same

Comment: Yes, onPostExecute() runs on UI thread, so you can set adapter data just in this method.
Instead of Data you can use String object of course.

Comment: as i am doing same ,the view item counts doesn't match with list size